# Replacing old with new in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Ok, let me be more specific; I am making a simple Celsius to Fahrenheit, and Fahrenheit to Celsius converter aid in my learning of JavaScript.

So, I have successfully made the converter work, and have it displayed in the DOM using new 'p' elements (which I will be later adding a border around in CSS).

**But what I am struggling with is having the new converted number cover the old one.**

Right now, you enter a number, it gives you the conversion(inside a 'p' element), then when you convert the next number, it gives you another. Until their is a list of conversions.

**What would I write into my code so that when you press "enter" the old result is replaced with the new?**

Here is the code thus far (I know it is probably very basic but I am very new to JavaScript):

```
            var celToFaren = {
        celcius: function(convert) {
            var c = Number(document.getElementById("celCount").value);
            var e = c * 9/5 + 32;
            if (c === 0) {
                alert('Please Enter a Number');
                return false;
            } else {
            var element = document.getElementById('div1');
            var resultShow = document.createElement('p');
            resultShow.textContent = c + ' ' + 'Celcius ' + 'is equal to ' + e + ' Farenhite';

            element.appendChild(resultShow);

            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: You probably want to use the `.innerHTML` property on dom elements. Then you can simply overwrite the content of the `div1` with your text.

Comment: Don't create a new `<p`> every time. Have a single `<p id="answer">` and then after you convert the temp, just use the _same <p>_ tag and replace the innerText. `document.getElementById('answer').innerText = "87 Celcius is equal to 179.6 Fahrenheit"`

Comment: yes - `element.appendChild` adds the new element as a new child of `element`, keeping what was there before. If you use `element.innerHTML` then you are replacing the old content with the new - which sounds like what you want here.

Comment: TJBlackman - if you had placed your answer as an answer and not in the comments I would have given you the tick. All the answers given here work, but yours and devutkarsh were the cleanest (making it easier for a beginner like me to understand and reread again when I go over it again).Thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are every time creating a new element and appending each time.

```
var resultShow = document.createElement('p');
```

What you need to do is create a blank 'p' element with an identifier and re-use it.
Eg. `<p id="result">`

Then on every enter instead of creating a new element, just use javascript selector method to replace the new value.
Eg. `document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = "new calculated value";`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much - your code works and was the cleanest method out of all the answers. Using this one line of code I have made four redundant. Again, thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Create a `p` element in your HTML code, just like the `div1` element.
Then change

```
var resultShow = document.createElement('p');
```

into

```
var resultShow = document.getElementById("result");
```

So:

```
var celToFaren = {
    celcius: function(convert) {
        var c = Number(document.getElementById("celCount").value);
        var e = c * 9/5 + 32;
        if (c === 0) {
            alert('Please Enter a Number');
            return false;
        } else {
        var element = document.getElementById('div1');
        var resultShow = document.getElementById("result");
        resultShow.textContent = c + ' ' + 'Celcius ' + 'is equal to ' + e + ' Farenhite';

        element.appendChild(resultShow);

        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer worker perfect - but I am "ticking the answer below because the code is a lot cleaner and easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

you can add an event listener that will w8 till the user press enter & there is a value at the input field.
so according to your code while C is the input field:

```
c.addEventListener("keypress", function(event){
    if(c.value.length > 0 && event.keycode == 13 ){
    resultShow.innerHTML = c + ' ' + 'Celcius ' + 'is equal to ' + e + ' Farenhite';
}
})
```

and you can learn more about keycode that define the number of each key pressed from this link:
https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be erasing your `div` content using `element.innerHTML ="";`like the following

```js
    var celToFaren = {
        celcius: function(convert,val) {
            var c = val
            var e = c * 9/5 + 32;
            if (c === 0) {
                alert('Please Enter a Number');
                return false;
            } else {
            var element = document.getElementById('div1');
            var resultShow = document.createElement('p');
            resultShow.textContent = c + ' ' + 'Celcius ' + 'is equal to ' + e + ' Farenhite';
            element.innerHTML ="";
            element.appendChild(resultShow);

            }
        }
    };
    
    celToFaren.celcius(null,20);
    celToFaren.celcius(null,50);
    celToFaren.celcius(null,100);
```

```html
<div id="div1">
</div>
```